# Looping images with different ID

Tags: javascript, react-native, foreach

In my react-native app I'm trying to loop images with different IDs and display them in my screen, I'm getting the ids correctly but when i try to loop them and display them in my FlatList only the image with the last id get displayed infinitely, here is my loop:

```
 IDs.forEach(async (element) => {
      imagesList = await this.getImagePreview(element);
      this.setState({images: imagesList });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you set the state of your images, you delete any previous completed requests. This means that which ever image request ends last will be the one you'll see.

You can take the Promise.all approach:

```
Promise.all(IDs.map((element) =>this.getImagePreview(element))
.then(res=>{
  this.setState({images: res.flat()});
});
```

Or this approach

```
this.setState({ images: [] });
IDs.forEach(async (element) => {
    const {images} = this.state;
    imagesList = await this.getImagePreview(element);
    this.setState({images: images.concat(imagesList) });
});
```

Adding [images](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image%5C) to your [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) taken straight from the docs:

```
  render(){

    const {images} = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={images}
          keyExtractor={(item, index)=>index}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={{uri:item}} />}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I'm setting the uri of the image inside the FlatList using this.state.images and it's returning that it should be converted to a valid url, can you help here please?

Comment: @MaryJane could provide more information ? What is the exact error ? Which line of code does it appear ? Can you provide an example of your url?

Comment: this.state. images returns all of the urls inside it and i guess that's the issue, i need to take them one by one and set them inside the image uri in my FlatList, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @MaryJane can you check the update and tell me if that answers your question? I'm also *completely* guessing what your `images` content looks like

Answer (score 0):

imagesList is a matrix, so you must insert the element in the last index in every forEach execution. What you're doing is overwriting it with an element, and that's why only the last one is rendered. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

```
IDs.forEach(async (element) => { 
  await this.setState({ images: this.state.images.push(this.getImagePreview(element)) });
});
```

Comment: push returns the length of the array.